# JPA inheritance without common fields

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

So I want to implement the existing DB-structure of my legacy system, but there are some issues.

I have three tables: `A`, `B`, and `C`.
 `A` contains the row `nr` which points to an entry of either `B` or `C`. The problem is that the primary key of `B` is `nr_b` and the primary key of `C` is `nr_c`.

I have a spring-boot application with a postgres DB behind it.

This is what i tried:

```
@Entity
class A {
    ...

    @Column(name="nr")
    private SuperBC item;

    ...
}

@MappedSuperClass
abstract class SuperBC {

    abstract Long getId();
    abstract void setId(Long id);
}

@Entity
class B extends SuperBC {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "nr_b")
    private Long id;

    ...
}

@Entity
class C extends SuperBC {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "nr_c")
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

This does not work because you cannot have a field annotated with `@MappedSuperClass`.
I also tried putting `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` instead of `@MappedSuperclass`, but then i have to also annotate `SuperBC` with `@Entity` and I have to create a field annotated with `@Id` which doesn't exist in my DB.

Is there a way to maybe manually write the mapping for the `A` class in the entityManager?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You could create two different views for the table `A`, map them as entitys and use them as relation entitys. The downside is: you can not update/insert them but you can store the detached table-entity.

Comment: Nice idea, but that would mean so much boilerplate code, I will do that if I cannot find any other possibility. But I wonder if this can be done with JPA in any way...

Comment: :D Database Normalization means less boilerplate but a reconstruction of your DB